# What is the term for a stalemate in Checkers?

Tags: checkers

What is the term for a stalemate in Checkers?  What are the official conditions for a "no winner game"?

Comment: Small nitpickery: the correct term is 'draw' in Chess _and_ Checkers.  'Stalemate' refers to a particular kind of draw in chess - namely, when a player is unable to move - that's all but impossible to achieve in Checkers.

Comment: 20 years ago a friend and I sat down to a game of checkers. I had been reading the Doadejing. He had been reading the Art of War. Neither of us ever made a jumping move. The pieces eventually moved from the horizontal to a diagonal set. In the end there were a couple kings owed on both sides. There was no way to jump. It was the best game I ever played. A total draw without losing a single piece.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

According to the [American Checker Federation](http://www.usacheckers.com/rulesofcheckers.php) (see rule 12), a tie game is called a **draw**.  The conditions for a draw are similar to the 50-move rule in chess.  Basically, one player asks the other to prove he can win (or get closer to winning) in the next 40 moves or the game ends in a draw.  I imagine this would only really occur in high level play, perhaps by several kinged pieces moving endlessly around the board with neither side gaining an advantage.

A condition like a stalemate in chess (where a player has no legal move to make) results in a loss for the player whose turn it is to move.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such term, because there is no such thing as a stalemate in checkers. It is always possible for at least one player to win, although in some cases that would require extraordinarily poor play by the other player.

EDIT to reply to comment:
I know this is really getting into semantics, but the question *is* about terminology. Your position seems to be that "stalemate" and "draw" are synonymous. I believe "stalemate" is merely the specific case where a player must move but cannot make a legal move, resulting in a draw. The very rule you cited states that, in checkers, if one player cannot make a legal move, the other player wins. By definition, that's not a draw, so in my mind, that's not a stalemate.

Comment: From Wikipedia -"A player wins by capturing all of the opposing player's pieces or by leaving the opposing player with no legal moves. The game ends in a draw, if neither side can force a win."

Comment: @Pat, please see my edit.

Comment: http://www.flickr.com/photos/perry_g/2064013288/ Looks like a stalemate to me.  There are several other stalemated checkers images on google as well.

Comment: @Pat, that's not a stalemate.  It's a loss for the player who has to move next (but can't, obviously).

Comment: @kristo - -1 for my reading comprehension!  Good catch.