# Is it possible to get a stalemate in Checkers?

Tags: end-game, checkers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the term for a stalemate in Checkers?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/2117/what-is-the-term-for-a-stalemate-in-checkers)

*I was going to post this in StackOverflow, when I realized it really has nothing to do with programming. If it has a better home, please say so, so I can move it there.*

I am making a basic Checkers game, and was setting up the game manager when I got to the method that gracefully ends the game. It would have taken in a `boolean` value, `true` signifying that player 1 has won, `false` signifying that player 2 has won. However, I realized that, in most games, there is the possibility of a stalemate, so I changed it to a `byte`, where `x < 0` is player 1, `x == 0` is a stalemate, and `x > 0` is player 2. After that, i started contemplating whether Checkers can even have a stalemate. It seems like it's possible, but for the life of me, I can't come up with a scenario where the game ends and neither player wins. **Is there any scenario, in the game of English Draughts (North American Checkers), where neither player wins the game, yet the game ends? Note that a forfeit on one player's part means that the other player wins.**

Comment: I believe the question I've linked to here answers your questions.  If not, please let me know - and welcome to B&CG!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not force capture then it's very possible, trivial even, to have a stalemate.

Even without though:

From wikipedia:

English draughts (American 8×8 checkers) has been the arena for several notable advances in game artificial intelligence. In the 1950s, Arthur Samuel created one of the first board game-playing programs of any kind. More recently, in 2007 scientists at the University of Alberta[13] evolved their "Chinook" program up to the point where it is unbeatable. A brute force approach that took hundreds of computers working nearly 2 decades was used to solve the game,[14] showing that a game of draughts will always end in a stalemate if neither player makes a mistake.[15][16] The solution is for the draughts variation called go-as-you-please (GAYP) checkers and not for the variation called three-move restriction checkers. As of December 2007, this makes English draughts the most complex game ever solved.