# Checkers only repetitive moves left to opponent

Tags: checkers

If opponent only can move between the two diagonal squares in the "open" corner, does he lose? How many times can he makes these fruitless moves?

Comment: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/2117/what-is-the-term-for-a-stalemate-in-checkers

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the term for a stalemate in Checkers?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/2117/6692)